# Fix Home Brew permissions on High Sierra

Tags: macos, homebrew, macos-high-sierra

I accidently tried renamed my home folder on my mac. Never. Ever. Do. That!  Homebrew no longer works... I get this error no matter what I try to install (or another github address).

`Error: Permission denied @ rb_sysopen - /private/tmp/github_api_headers20180921-5820-13099yc`.

Nothing works, not even wget or mysql.

I tried uninstalling / re-installing but doesn't work.

`ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/uninstall)"`

How can I fix homebrew? Is it necessary to wipe the whole computer?

Answer (score 0):

Files under `/Users/myuser` should have ownership to `myuser` and group ownership to `staff`.

I don't know your specific settings but before to wipe out your system you could try to restore these basic ownerships with:

```
chown -R myuser:staff /Users/myuser
```

where `myuser` is the name of your user. As I said, I don't know anything about your specific settings so do this at your own risk.

Comment: Thank for the answer @Ortomala but it didn't solve my problem. Solved it by wiping my machine, now it works again...